# Two \maketitle in the document: an issue with \thanks

Tags: titles

I need to have two \maketitles in a document. The titling package handles this almost perfectly. The issue is that I use the \thanks command in the \title and in the \author, and then, in the second \maketitle, the text of the \thanks command is repeated twice. Does anyone know how I can get rid of the second occurrence of the text of the \thanks command?
Thanks,
Eilon

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\title{First title\thanks{I thank my kids.}}
\author{Author1\thanks{Affiliation of author1. } and Author2\thanks{Affiliation of author2.}}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
\title{Second title}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX collects all footnotes added by `\thanks` commands in a macro `\@thanks`; it has to be emptied before typesetting the second title. To avoid that the second title page resets the page counter, we use the `xpatch` package and modify the `titlepage` environment; this is a hack, though. Alternatively, you can set the page number manually using `\setcounter{page}{... desired page number ...}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mytitlepage}%
  {\begin{titlepage}\def\@thanks{}}%
  {\end{titlepage}}
\xpatchcmd\titlepage{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\endtitlepage{\setcounter{page}\@ne}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{mytitlepage}
\title{First title\thanks{I thank my kids.}}
\author{Author1\thanks{Affiliation of author1.}
    and Author2\thanks{Affiliation of author2.}}
\maketitle
\end{mytitlepage}

\begin{mytitlepage}
\title{Second title}
\maketitle
\end{mytitlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact, there is a slight problem with the solution: it creates TWO pages that are numbered 1 (the first page and the second page). This happens twice, once for each title. (To see the problem, add text after each title). Any solution?

Comment: @Eilon I have modified my solution to handle the page number issue.