# How to create two different title pages with the \maketitle command?

Tags: titles, titling

I would like to create two different title pages (one with the author information and the thanks notes and one without) by using the \maketitle command. Repeating the commands one after another wasn't successful.

Using the \titling package creates the same title, even though I enter an empty field for the author (i.e., \author{}) and insert no \thanks notes after the title.

Is there an elegant and an easy way to create two different title pages with different information? I would be glad, if someone can help me here.

Here is the code I tried running with the \titling package, which repeats the same titlepage:

```
\title{Title text\thanks{Thanks}}

\author{Author Name}

\date{D}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\oneandhalfspacing

\begin{titlepage}

\maketitle 

\date{}

\begin{abstract}

\spacing{2}

\thispagestyle{empty}

Some text for the abstract

\end{abstract}

\end{titlepage}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\oneandhalfspacing

\begin{titlepage}

\maketitle

\date{}

\title{Title Text}

\author{}

\date{}

\begin{abstract}

\spacing{2}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\date{}

Some text for the abstract

\end{abstract}

\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\spacing{2}

\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: Possible answer (already in earlier posts): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335479/two-maketitle-in-the-document-an-issue-with-thanks?rq=1

Comment: I have already seen the entry posted, thanks! It didn't work for me, though. @John Kormylo, I am not sure, if I understand your comment fully. Could you please let me know how to modify the preamble and the text code (I now edited my entry)?

Comment: The above mentioned earlier post helped me solve the problem after looking into the code in detail! Thanks for mentioning it again!

Comment: Never mind.  Didn't work.